# npm install error while installing posix

Tags: linux, node.js, centos, npm, posix

I am new for nodejs and npm. I want to install p3(https://github.com/digitalbazaar/p3). Firstly I must install bedrock(github.com/digitalbazaar/bedrock) as it is written in instruction but at the command "npm install" in bedrock folder it fails. It seems like that npm or something cannot compile some posix source files. Console output :

```
[root@localhost bedrock]# npm install
npm WARN package.json bedrock@1.0.2-dev No license field.

posix@1.0.4 install /root/bedrock/node_modules/posix
node-gyp rebuild

make: Entering directory `/root/bedrock/node_modules/posix/build'
  CXX(target) Release/obj.target/posix/src/posix.o
../src/posix.cc:16:41: error: ‘Arguments’ does not name a type
 static Handle<Value> node_getppid(const Arguments& args) {
                                         ^
../src/posix.cc:16:52: error: ISO C++ forbids declaration of ‘args’ with no type [-fpermissive]
 static Handle<Value> node_getppid(const Arguments& args) {
                                                    ^
In file included from /root/.node-gyp/0.12.4/src/node.h:61:0,
                 from ../src/posix.cc:1:
```

Full console output: http://pastebin.com/HdTvNNMz

```
My configuration
[root@localhost bedrock]# node -v
v0.12.4
[root@localhost bedrock]# npm -v
2.10.1
[root@localhost bedrock]# uname -a
Linux localhost.localdomain 3.10.0-229.el7.x86_64 #1 SMP Fri Mar 6 11:36:42 UTC 2015 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Answer (score 1):

The version of `bedrock` that `payswarm-auth` depends on is too old. Not only has `posix` been updated to use `nan` for compatibility with newer versions of node/io.js, but newer versions of `bedrock` don't even use `posix` at all.

Comment: But how not to use it if bedrock needs it by default. Is here any possibility?

Comment: What I was getting at is that you should probably create an issue on `payswarm-auth`'s [github repo](https://github.com/digitalbazaar/p3/issues/new) telling them to upgrade their `bedrock` dependency.